# GCC will compile but clang wont

Tags: c, gcc, clang

So in my finals there was an exercise asking what will the program print.

This is the code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main (){
    int x=5, y=4;

    if (x>y);
      printf("A");

    if(x=4)
      printf("%d",x+y);

     return 0;
}
```

When I try to compile it using `gcc -ansi -pedantic -Werror` on a Debian machine, it compiles just fine and outputs "A8".

However, when I try to compile it using `clang -ansi -pedantic -Werror`, I receive errors regarding the `if (x=4)` expression missing `=` and missing statement on `if(x>y);`.

Why does that happen, and which answer could be marked as correct?

Comment: `=` is not the same operator as `==`.

Comment: Yes I do get that.What I do not understand is why it compiles in GCC and it does not in clang.

Comment: So apparently `gcc` is believing that you know what you are doing, while `clang` is not :)

Comment: `if (x>y); printf("A");` is equal to `if (x>y) { /* empty block */ } printf("A");`

Comment: Does `gcc -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic` make any difference?

Comment: Not the answer, but the `-ansi` flag is misleading. It might not do what you think it does (it's equivalent to `-std=c90`). You might want to use a more recent standard, like `-std=c11`.

Comment: GCC accepts conforming code by default. Clang has more enabled-by-default warnings that become errors with `-Werror`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

compilers may emit different warnings. For example `clang` warns about empty statement and `gcc` does not.

So if you set -Werror it will compile using gcc but will not compile using the clang.

BTW what is stopping you from reading the compiler messages. They are self-explanatory. It even shows how to correct it.

```
#1 with x86-64 clang 9.0.0
```

```
<source>:6:9: error: if statement has empty body [-Werror,-Wempty-body]

if (x>y);

        ^

<source>:6:9: note: put the semicolon on a separate line to silence this warning

<source>:8:5: error: using the result of an assignment as a condition without parentheses [-Werror,-Wparentheses]

if(x=4)

   ~^~

<source>:8:5: note: place parentheses around the assignment to silence this warning

if(x=4)

    ^

   (  )

<source>:8:5: note: use '==' to turn this assignment into an equality comparison

if(x=4)

    ^

    ==

<source>:12:2: error: no newline at end of file [-Werror,-Wnewline-eof]

}

 ^

3 errors generated.

Compiler returned: 1
```